# List all public gitHub repositories as links

Tags: github, web-crawler, archiving

I need an index-page, that shows links to all gitHub repositories.

I think that is the reason, why many repos are not found by crawlers like the [Waybackmachine](http://archive.org/web/web.php)

I think if there was such a site with a high ranking, they would start crawling it

The developer site sais, there is an [Api for getting all repos](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-repositories)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how this is a programming related question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to program a huge index-page, that contains links to all gitHub repositories. (only if it doesen't already exist, but I fond none, searching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning:** GitHub hosts a **huge** number of repositories. You'll have to take this into account when designing your index.

I can think of a few options:

- The **[legacy GitHub search API](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories)**. You'll have to cope with the **[API rate limit](http://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting)** though.
- This **[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12773331/335418)** could be a good start to get a rough grasp of the number of repos per language.
- Leveraging the **[GitHub Archive](http://www.githubarchive.org/)** project which records the public GitHub timeline. (*Note:* As the project only exposes events back from February 12, 2011, you won't get any data about repositories showing no activity since this date.)

Comment: I don´t think using the search API can list all repos. There is a 1000 limit for any query. You can´t pass page "10" with the maximum 100 records per page. Repos per language has flaws, regarding javascript x Ruby. I think the only way is using the repositories API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449038/is-there-any-link-to-show-all-public-repositories-in-github?lq=1